# Expandable listview group indicator change automatically when it get focused

Tags: android, focus, expandablelistview

I'm working with expandable listview. Everything works fine. But when group item get focused the indicator of the group view gets into normal state (minimized) even if that list is expanded. I don't know why this is happen? Any idea on this??

Before:

[image]

After get focused:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I have solve same thing with the Button. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339036/on-click-of-android-listview-items-child-elements-like-button-are-getting-foc/12836823#12836823).