# On click of Android listview item's child elements (like button) are getting focus

Tags: android, listview, focus

### I have a listview. Each item in listview is customized. Each item has

text view1

### text view2  button1

text view1

### text view2  button1

text view1

### text view2  button1

on click of item buttons are getting focus. I don't want to get the focus of button even though i have given the following attributes of button in each listview item's layout
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
Any one please help me out this

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

Just Focuable false on entire the Layout.

Comment: If you don't required any click event than,, Use This :   android:enabled="false"

Comment: Both list item and button have separate click events, that work fine but on click of item button is getting foucs

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DontPressWithParentButton extends Button {

public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    if (pressed && getParent() instanceof View && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
}
}
```

Add the following element in layout file

`<DontPressWithParentButton />`

Hope this works fine without any flaws

Answer (score 0):

Before some days i have face same problem. But now i have solve it.

Do like following.

Make One class called **DontPressWithParentButton** which extends Button like below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DontPressWithParentButton extends Button {

    public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed && getParent() instanceof View && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }

}
```

Now, in your item row xml, define Button as like below 
(add your package in place of YOUR_APP_PACKAGE)

```
<YOUR_APP_PACKAGE.DontPressWithParentButton android:id="@+id/deleteBtn" android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Approve"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            />
```

Now reference id in your java file like below:

```
DontPressWithParentButton deleteGameBtn=(DontPressWithParentButton) findViewById(R.id.deleteGameBtn);
```

Now run the project. You will get what you want.

comment me if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` so that child View(row ) can be blocked.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

And if you want the **vise wersa** than add `focusable and focusableInTouchMode to false` to `imageButton/Button` in item.xml